# How to resolve 404 errors while using sudo apt-get update

Tags: apt, updates, sudo, ppa

I found these errors while using `sudo apt-get update`. I tried to resolve this issue by adding repository using `sudo` command but it did not resolve yet. It will be helpful if anyone can solve this issue.

```
Err:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/marutter/c2d4u/ubuntu artful Release                                                                                                                                       
  404  Not Found

Err:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make/ubuntu artful Release                                                                                                                           
  404  Not Found

Err:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/gnome3/ubuntu artful Release                                                                                                                                   
  404  Not Found
```

Comment: For the first one, have a look at the site in a browser, when you get to http://ppa.launchpad.net/marutter/c2d4u/ubuntu/dists/ you'll note there is no Artful directory - ie. 17.10 isn't supported for the PPA  (*my answer is worded this way as I read it as you were seeking help in solving issue, rather than quick fix; some PPAs only support LTS releases*)

Answer (score 1):

By example in 'how to resolve errors', for the first one, have a look at the site in a browser, when you get to

http://ppa.launchpad.net/marutter/c2d4u/ubuntu/dists/

you'll note there is no "artful" directory - ie. 17.10 isn't supported for this PPA which results in the error you got.  *Artful is the code name for the 17.10 release*

(*my answer is worded this way as I read it as you were seeking help in solving issue, rather than quick fix; some PPAs only support LTS releases, or many  other reasons*)

Comment: How can I resolve this issue.

Comment: All three PPAs listed don't support your release of Ubuntu, so you need to find another source/solution for whatever you want/need.  Your question asked about the PPA not working and how to resolve; those PPAs don't support Artful Aardvark so can't be used with Artful. **Any more requires me to know why you added them which you didn't provide** as those PPAs aren't intended to work with 17.10.  It may be you could download (`wget`) whatever you want intended for another release, and install it manually, but this has drawbacks (you have to manually check for updates...) etc